# makefile for latex aspell with multiple files

Tags: makefile, latex, aspell

I neeed to run aspell on all tex files within a directory using a makefile

```
spellcheck:
    @aspell --lang=en -t -c sections/*tex
```

does not work as aspell cannot handle multiple files. How can I run multiple runs of aspell one after another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a rule to run each file

```
TEX_FILES = $(wildcard sections/*.tex)
.PHONY: spellcheck
spellcheck: $(addsuffix .spchk,$(basename $(TEX_FILES)))

%.spchk: %.tex
    @aspell --lang=en -t -c $<
```

Comment: check for correct makefile indentation when copying the code above